# Find the first three terms in a geometric series using the given sum and product

Tags: math, regression, numerical-methods, quadratic

My goal is to create a **C++ program** that computes a geometric sequence's first three terms. What is provided is the sum of the first three terms and their multiplication.

It is assumed that the answers have to be real.

I get
`b = p¹ᐟ³`
and
`a² + (b-s)a + b² = 0`

Comment: ```I tried solving on paper and implementing my thought process but it seems like a bad idea.``` Actually, that would seem quite a GOOD idea.

Comment: You have a known sum `a + b + c` and a known product `abc`. For a geometric sequence `a,b,c`, you also know that `b/a` is equal to `c/b`. That should be a good start.

Comment: if your way on paper is still bad, you shouldnt even think about writing the code. Writing code without having a clear idea of what the code should do can only result in a mess. Do the maths first

Comment: I removed the c++ tag, because at the current stage the language is not relevant. Once you know the formulas and you wrote some code you can still ask  a quesiton about c++.

Comment: And last but not least,welcome to SO! Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. This will grant you your first badge.

Comment: The product will give you the middle term easily enough, but the common ratio, and hence the other two terms, may have 0, 1 or 2 solutions for any given sum and product.

Comment: @wienio03 Are we dealing with real numbers, or can they be complex? If the series is `a b c`, and the common ratio is `r = b/a = c/b`, are `a` and `r` both real numbers?

Comment: Thats not specified in the task. I would assume its real numbers only. I think my idea on paper is good, but it wasn't clear to me whether if I can use any already implemented functions for getting a square or cube root so I thought that there has to be some unique weird way of doing it differently than from those 2 equations and the fact we can easily get x2 from the product of terms. Thanks for answers and sorry if the question was unclear. Its my first post 

Comment: _it wasn't clear to me whether if I can use any already implemented functions for getting a square or cube root_ – You'll have to check with your source, but it is likely okay to use library functions such as the C++ functions `sqrt` and `pow`.

Comment: My last question is for example when operating with floats when calculating the discriminant and determinining whether if it is >0 or ==0 can be tricky due to the floating point number representation. Should I check if the absolute value of result minus epsilon is equal to 0? The absolute error is stated in the task to be less than 10^-25 or relative error is less than 10^-6.

Comment: Just added this to my answer: The factors of equation (8), therefore, provide a good indication of whether round-off error in a computer computation is affecting the analysis of the discriminant. If either factor is "close" to zero, then the sign of the discriminant may not be computed correctly. In addition, a discriminant that should be valued at 0, may be computed as some "small" value, either positive or negative.

Comment: _For those not yet in the know:_ For sensitive computer computations, such as those involving the discriminant, use double-precision (i.e., type `double` in C++). DO NOT use single-precision (i.e., type `float`). The round-off errors with type `float` accumulate too quickly for that type to be useful here.

Comment: In the task I have to complete it is specified the keyword "double" is banned so I am forced to use single-precision.

Comment: So, your instructor is deliberately introducing error. He wants type `float` to fail, so that he can see whether you are correctly implementing the error-detection thresholds given above.

Comment: How exactly do I make sure the error-detection thresholds are implemented correctly? Do I make procedures that calculate relative error and absolute error and just simply check them in an if statement instead of checking values directly?

Answer (score 2):

Let `a` `b` `c` be real numbers that are the first three terms of a [geometric series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series). Assume none of them are 0. Otherwise, the "series" is degenerate.

Let ratio `r` be a real number that is the ratio between successive terms. Thus,

```
r = b/a                                   (1)
r = c/b                                   (2)
```

Solving equations (1) and (2) for `a` and `c` gives:

```
a = b/r                                   (3)
c = br                                    (4)
```

Given the product `p`, equations (3) and (4) let us find `b` directly:

```
p = abc = (b/r)(b)(br)
p = bbb = b³
b = p¹ᐟ³                                  (5)
```

Thus, `b` is the cube root of the product.

[*Note:* There are only two fractional exponents used in this answer: 1/3 and 2/3. If the tiny Unicode exponents are hard to read, you may want to zoom in.]

Setting equation (1) equal to equation (2) gives another equation for `c`:

```
b/a = c/b
bb = ac
b² = ac
c = b²/a
c = (p¹ᐟ³)²/a
c = p²ᐟ³/a                                (6)
```

Turning to sum `s`, we have:

```
s = a + b + c
s = a + (p¹ᐟ³) + (p²ᐟ³/a)
```

Mulitplying both sides by `a`, and then subtracting `as` from both sides, yields:

```
as = aa + a(p¹ᐟ³) + a(p²ᐟ³/a)
sa = a² + (p¹ᐟ³)a + p²ᐟ³
0 = a² + (p¹ᐟ³)a - sa + p²ᐟ³
0 = a² + (p¹ᐟ³-s)a + p²ᐟ³                 (7)
```

Equation (7) can be solved by the familiar [quadratic formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_formula). For the quadratic equation `0 = Ax² + Bx + C`, where upper-case letters are used to distinguish from the lower-case ones above, we can map equation (7) as follows:

- `A` is `1`
- `B` is `p¹ᐟ³-s`
- `C` is `p²ᐟ³`
- `x` is `a`

The *discriminant,* `B² - 4AC`, determines the number and type of the roots.

- *positive* — There are two distinct real number roots
- *zero* – There is a single, real number root. This is sometimes called a *double root*.
- *negative* – The two roots are complex conjugates.

For equation (7), we have

```
B² = (p¹ᐟ³-s)²
B² = (p¹ᐟ³)² + 2(p¹ᐟ³)(-s) +(-s)²
B² = p²ᐟ³ - 2s(p¹ᐟ³) + s²

4AC = 4(1)(p²ᐟ³)
4AC = 4p²ᐟ³

B² - 4AC = p²ᐟ³ - 2s(p¹ᐟ³) + s² - 4p²ᐟ³
B² - 4AC = -3p²ᐟ³ - 2s(p¹ᐟ³) + s²
B² - 4AC = s² - 2(p¹ᐟ³)s - 3p²ᐟ³
B² - 4AC = (s + p¹ᐟ³)(s - 3p¹ᐟ³)          (8)
B² - 4AC = (s + b)(s - 3b)               (9)
```

Equation (9) shows that the discriminant vanishes in two cases:

1. `s = -b`
2. `s = 3b`

A program designed to find `a`, `b`, and `c` for the geometric series of this question must analyze the discriminant, and present solutions accordingly.

For the real number solutions that exist:

- Equation (7) can be can be solved to determine the value of `a`
- Equation (5) gives `b`
- Equation (6) gives `c`

The factors of equation (8) provide a good indication of whether round-off error in a computer computation is affecting the analysis of the discriminant. If either factor is "close" to zero, then the sign of the discriminant may not be computed correctly. In addition, a discriminant that should be valued at 0, may be computed as some "small" value, either positive or negative.

Comment: I got to equation (7) by myself before the post but numerical analysis/methods is a new thing for me and I thought instantly my solution would be really inefficient. Thanks again.

Comment: @wienio03 different notations and methods are efficient with pen and paper vs in code. You first need to know the analytical solution, then you can consider how to implement it in an efficient algorithm. Factorial is good example for what I mean. It is extremely convenient analytically to write eg `x! / (x-n)!` but implementing this literally in code would be far from optimal

Comment: I was wondering whether if just simply calculating the roots of a quadratic equation like we are taught in school to find the common ratio is more efficient in this case than using for example secants method? The main problem I have here with secants method is how do I find a good beginning values of a and b for the starting [a,b] interval in which im looking for a root?

Comment: Why would you even consider the secant method? It's iterative, requires a good initial guess, fails to tell you whether a solution exists, ... Just use the standard quadratic formula.

Comment: My last question is for example when operating with floats when calculating the discriminant and determinining whether if it is >0 or ==0 can be tricky due to the floating point number representation. Should I check if the absolute value of result minus epsilon is equal to 0? The absolute error is less than 10^-25 or relative error is less than 10^-6.

Comment: I suspect that you are only going to be asked for one solution anyway, so as long as your discriminant is >=0 then I wouldn't worry about such niceties. I suspect that you are over-thinking the problem.